# Create unique ID for users offer

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a SQL-table for user information and a table for offers. If a user uploads an offer, it gets a unique id, aswell as a "belonging_id" with the users id in it.

Now I want to change an element after the offer is already in my Database. But the only information I have is the user's id. And it is possible for a user to have multiple offers.

So my Question is: How can I call one specific offer with a unique id to Update it?

Comment: "the only information I have is the user's id". Why do you only have the user's ID? Can you get the offer's ID instead? (Since each offer can only belong to one user it's easy to find the user to which the offer belongs. Not so the other way.)

Comment: Same Q as chris. If all you know is the user's ID, the solution is to improve the front-end code that submits the request so that it includes info that can uniquely identify the offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be, you can make your table as 3-column table, like this:

```
+----+--------------+----------+
| id | belonging_id | offer_id |
+----+--------------+----------+
|    |              |          |
```

`id` column would be `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `PRIMARY KEY`, `belonging_id` would be user's id and and `offer_id` would be your unique offer id. This way, you can satisfy the following condition,

> And it is possible for a user to have multiple offers.

An example table snippet would be like this:

```
+----+--------------+----------+
| id | belonging_id | offer_id |
+----+--------------+----------+
|  1 |      A       |     XYZ  |
|  2 |      A       |     ABC  |
|  3 |      A       |     PQR  |
|  4 |      B       |     IJK  |
+----+--------------+----------+
```

Now, you can select a particular `<belonging_id, offer_id>` pair using the `id` column value.

---

**Sidenote:** If you're planning to use this method and insert records in this table, look at the following links to get last inserted id (pick one as per your extension),

- [mysqli::$insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)
- [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Answer (score 0):

Please give us your SQL Table schemes.

To help you, I think your request should be something like :

`SELECT * FROM offers WHERE belonging_id = id_user`

---

**EDIT :**

You need to have a `unique identifier` (something like primary key, or a `UNIQUE` field) in your table offers if you want to retrieve a specific offer among all the user's offers.

When you insert data in a table, you can retrieve the last inserted id.
For exemple, in **PHP** (*using PDO extension*) you can do : `echo $db->lastInsertId();`

---

**EDIT 2:**

Let's suppose the user ends on a page `send_offer.php` after he sent the offer in the database.
You should then generate a unique link like : `http://edit_offer.php/?id_offer=the_id_of_the_offer_just_sent`

This unique link should be stored in your table offers, so when the user wants to edit one of his offer, he only has to access your site with this link.

This link should point to a web page where there's a form, in which you'll want to load the data of the offer corresponding to the above link.

Comment: I thought about that too, but if a user can have multiple offers, it won't be unique anymore ...

Comment: Yes, this should work, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- A user has multiple offers
- You want to edit a specific offer
- All you know is the user's identity

What you're asking has no coding solution because it has no logical solution. It's like if I gave you a jar of blue and white marbles and I asked you to bring me a specific blue marble. All you know is the color so without further info there is no way to reliably get the marble I want.

Instead of trying to devise a solution on the server end, turn to the front-end. Figure out how to send info that will uniquely identify the request, along with the userID. For instance, include the offer ID in the request `process.php?offer_ID=123` so you can retrieve it with `$_GET['offer_id']` and use it in the query.

If you have no way to do it all in one step, you could instead:

1. `SELECT * FROM offers WHERE belonging_id = $userID`
2. Send all results to the front end, with their offer IDs attached
3. Ask the user to select a specific offer from the matches, and return its ID to the server
4. `SELECT * FROM offers WHERE offer_id = $offerID` and process that record